# django template forloop.counter question

Tags: css, django, forms, templates

i have many fields in my form i was trying to apply different css to neighbour forms fields like

```
<li class='thiscolor' >
   <field>
</li>

<li class='thatcolor' >
   <field>
</li>
```

if there a way like

```
{% for field in form %}
    **{% if forloop.counter%2 == 0 %}**
   <li class='thiscolor'>
    {% else%}
   <li class='thatcolor'>     
    {%endif}
     {{field}}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

for forloop.counter  ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [cycle tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) is designed for this type of problem:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <li class="{% cycle 'thiscolor' 'thatcolor' %}">{{ field }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 21):

I agree with Jarret that `cycle` is best here, but to actually answer the question, the `%2==0` operation can be replicated by using the `divisibleby` filter.

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to keep in mind is that since this is a front end problem - the styling is what you're trying to effect - you can solve it on the front end. There's a good example provided toward the bottom of this [A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebratables/). Of course, if you've already got working Django code there's no sense in doing this now.

Comment: Yes, but templates are certainly the front-end portion of Django (the "V" in MVC).

Comment: Right that, rather, it's a styling issue that can be alternately handled client side (CSS).